# Bootstrap 5 Grid Button Placement; I'm a Novice Developer and this last button is driving me insane

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-5

I am creating this web portfolio for my web design class and our teacher requires that we use Bootstrap 5 (I wish I could just use HTML and Vanilla CSS). After a lot of tinkering I finally was able to get my elements to respond correctly for desktop, tablet, and mobile device break points. EXCEPT for the "View More" button on lg screen breakpoint; I simply want to place the same style button underneath the "I'm Nate Finn. Graphic Des...." photo in my desktop version without messing up the order of my photos or sending it down below in which it looks like a footer element. (I am very new to this obviously so please excuse my ignorance). I have attached screenshots that included the empty space where I want to center the button and this is my code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="text-center col-lg-7 ms-sm-auto ps-sm-5 pe-sm-5"><img class="img-fluid pt-5" src="image/welcomemsg.png" alt="Welcome Message">
                <img class="img-fluid d-none d-lg-block" src="image/blurb.png" alt="I'm Nate Finn"></div>
              <div class="text-end col-5 order-lg-1 order-md-2 order-2">
                  <img class="img-fluid pt-5 float-end" src="image/Resizeme.jpg" alt="Vector Cartoon of Face and Torso"></div>
              <div class="text-center col-7 order-lg-2 d-lg-none order-md-1 order-lg-0 ps-sm-5 pe-sm-5">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="image/Intro.png" alt="I'm Nate Finn">
                <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">View More</button></div>
</section>
```

LG
[image]

SM
[image]

Comment: So I added the bootstrap css cdn to your example but I didn't change the formatting or syntax in any way. In it lies part of your culprit wherein you're missing a couple closing tags for divs and your columns can only equal 12 total in a row, you might also work on improving your formatting better practices of your html if you're getting into web development, just a tip. Now, were you wanting someone to just go take what ya got and show you how to do it correctly or did you want to correct your syntax errors first?

Comment: @ChrisW. Hey chris! Thank you man first of all. I would definitely love to start correcting the syntax errors first because I know all of this is very sloppy and the columns don't add up correctly. If you are willing to help me correct the errors and also show me how to do it correctly according to my desired layout that would be fantastic. I just didn't want to overreach and ask too much. This is only our first draft so if you just wanted to show me the quicker fix for now, thats completely up to you! Appreciate you, will definitely be upvoting and probably sending a tip your way for the help